# Live streaming from Windows IoT Raspberry pi 3 c#

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, iot, live-streaming, windows-10-iot-core

I have been working on raspberry pi 3 with windows iot os. Now i want to stream from my raspberry pi device and the streaming output should be visible in my windows 10 pc. I am testing with two raspberry pi devices. So my goal is to display the streaming output of two devices in my windows 10 pc.

I have tried few methods available over the internet neither of them work fully (simple communication sample project from windows iot samples works but very slow and the quality of the output video is not great and it breaks partially).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you've tried

Comment: "*visible in my windows 10 pc*" like how? Website, desktop app, notification, performance counter??

Comment: What are you streaming? Data or Video or ...?

Comment: @PeterBons I want the output to be streamed in web browser. Actually i wanted to use youtube api but i couldn't find any docs for iot

Comment: @Fildor yes,i am streaming video.

Comment: @Twyxz i tried from this sample  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication/cs/Scenario2_VideoChat.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/SaschaIoT/HttpWebcamLiveStream) on GitHub, it is a simple webcam video live stream in the browser.Or you can refer to [WebcamApp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/WebcamApp), it creates an app that initializes a web cam, takes pictures, and records video and audio.